# rest - java 16 digit number data type

Tags: java, type-conversion

i wonder what data type should i use for 16 digit number in my rest api, since Integer would return 400 bad request, i had to modify it to another data type,

> `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleTypeMismatch Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Integer]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1111111111111111"`

thank you.

Comment: If it's numeric, `BigDecimal`. If it's really indicative, like a credit card number, `String`.

Comment: You can simply take as a BigInteger.

Comment: What’s wrong with a `long`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply accept it as a `String x` and then convert it into [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) as

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(x);
```

Comment: is it okay to use BigInt in my entity, dao, dto, and service class?

Comment: I don't see a harm in such case, as long as there is a need of such big representation of integer values.

Comment: Why not using `long`? If its gurantied to never exceed 16 digits, than the long datatype should be able to handel it.

Comment: @n247s Agreed. But ideally I would expect that also to be converted from a string instead of casting directly.

Comment: @nullpointer Where would it be casted directly? It has to be parsed from a String either internally (which failed for the Integer type) or externally (your solution). Anyway, I guese the OP has enough information to solve his problem.